# How to update / delete then recreate an app that must be updated

Tags: app, template

I'm using SharePoint Online.  I've created a Document Library that support a particular content type.  I've saved this as a Template at the top level site in my site collection so that it is available to all sub sites.

Is it possible to update the template after it is created?  Perhaps I should delete the template and simply create the updated one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete template and create new one, there nothing like *"re-saved as existing template"* doesn't exist.